# Build a rolling sum across a date and attribute

Tags: spotfire

I have weekly data for Products and Markets from an Information Link. I want to create a rolling 12 week sum across the Date AND the Market (in this instance, Product A is always Product A) as a Calculated Column. On other Information Links without a Market, I have used `Sum([DOLLARS]) OVER (LastPeriods(12,[DATE]))`. Now, I need to do something like `Sum([DOLLARS]) OVER ([MARKET1], LastPeriods(4,[WEEK_ENDING_DATE]))`, however I cannot figure out the exact syntax.

Below is an example of the data:
[image]

In summary, I am trying to build a rolling sum column across a Date Hierarchy AND an attribute. The `OVER` syntax does not seem to support `LastPeriods` and an attribute together.

Comment: Have you tried the `Intersect` keyword? For example `Sum([DOLLARS]) OVER Intersect([MARKET1], LastPeriods(4,[WEEK_ENDING_DATE]))`

Comment: That worked. I guess I was confused by the wording of the usage for `Intersect`. It sounds like it works across two hierarchies. `MARKET1` is technically just an attribute in this case, but good to know. If you want to make that an answer, Ill accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `Intersect` keyword:

```
Sum([DOLLARS]) OVER Intersect([MARKET1], LastPeriods(4,[WEEK_ENDING_DATE]))
```